# Advantages of AirNotifier and Parse-Server?

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

As for my bachelor thesis, I’m wondering which are the advantages of air notifier and Parse Server as a push notification service than the other services like pushd, Aerogear, etc…

Answer (score 1):

**AirNotifier** is a server for sending only push notifications and that's it. so this server expose API endpoint that can be triggered by the client to send a push notification for one or more devices.

**parse-server** is a MBAAS (mobile backend as a service) open source platform which allows you to have a backend up and running without any effort. The idea behind MBAAS is that developers will focus on developing the client app and the platform will take care the server side. so parse-server do the following in order to make it happen:

1. Expose dynamic endpoints - when you develop your own backend you are required to expose API's to your clients so each of the API needs to be implemented by the server side developers in any server side programming language (e.g. NodeJS, Jave, Python etc.). In parse it is done automatically because it know how to expose it automatically for you.
2. Handle push notifications - with parse-server you can easily send push notifications to your users. First you need to subscribe the user and store it in the DB and then you need to call the push endpoint (also exposed automatically with parse) and send the API's to which device/s you like to send the message and the server will do the rest
3. Cloud code - in order your app to be more flexible parse-server created something they call cloud code. Cloud code are divided into 2 types: custom functions that can run on the server and should be triggered by the client and events that are triggered automatically by the parse-server core when something is created/deleted/changed.
4. Client SDK's - parse-server provides client SDK's for most of the programming languages like: iOS, Android, PHP, Javascript and more. those client SDK's are very powerful and contains a tons of features and are very easy to use
5. There are more things like: email integration, user management, auto sync between client and server, social login and more and more..

So to summarize it: AirNotifier will only provide app server that will simply the push notification process. 
parse-server will simply your whole backend.

BTW! parse-server is 100% NodeJS implementation and it stores the data in MongoDB. if you want to use it you need to learn how to configure it and deploy it to the cloud other than that you will need to have basic NodeJS skills.
parse-server is the open source version of the popular parse.com service which will not be available on January 2017

you can read more here:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

Hope it's clear now :)